# I am trying to run this C++ code but its showing me error, can you tell me what is wrong?

Tags: c++

```
int initfunc(int *array, int len) 
{
    int i;

    for(i=1; i <= len; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *myarray = 0;

    initfunc(myarray, 10);
}
```

I have run this code in C++ but showing me error. can you please tell me what is wrong with code.

Comment: can you add which error is shown, and on which line?

Comment: You are accessing memory out of bounds because you treat a null pointer as if it pointed to an array.

Comment: so what do i have to change in this code?

Comment: you need to allocate enough space for `myarray`. `int myarray[10]`.

Comment: it says error on line 10.

Comment: Is there a reason you are starting a `array[1]` instead of `array[0]` in the `initfunc` function?

Comment: Your `initfunc` should be declared as returning `void` since you are returning a constant value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Okay first of all you have to change the line

```
int *myarray = 0;
```

You have two options you can generate an array on the stack and on the heap. The stack example looks like this:

```
int myarray[10];
```

Where 10 is the size of you array.
Second your for loop is running out of bounds. You have to start with the index 0 and iterate up to array size -1. In our example 10-1=9

So you have to change the line

```
for(i=1; i <= len; i++)
```

to

```
for(i=0; i < len; i++)
```

the whole project should look like this:

```
int initfunc(int *array, int len) 
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int myarray[10];

    initfunc(myarray, 10);
}
```

I'm ignoring certain "best practices" in this example to be as close to your code as possible. One good intention would be to declare the length of that array just once and also bring that int i into the loop scope. Im leaving this here for you to try and exercise.

Comment: What about the `return 0` at the end of `initfunc`?  This function should return `void` since the return value never changes.

Comment: Yep you are completely right! Thanks @ThomasMatthews kinda forgot about that.